# onRestoreInstanceState accessing private variables in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have some private Int variables initialized in kotlin.

```
class multiply : AppCompatActivity() {
.
.
private var score:Int=0;
private var score2=0;
.
.
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState==null) {
            score=score2;

        }

.
.
     }
.
.
    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        score=savedInstanceState.getInt("val_score");
     }
```

My question is while I rotate my phone, a new is activity is created and in the present code score is getting assigned to 0. Is there any way for initializing only once? What is the way out?

I have some calculations inside onCreate using score. Since onRestoreInstanceState is executed after onCreate is there any way to keep the value of score unaffected on screen rotation other than defining it in onStart?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
class MultiplyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var score = 0;
    private var score2 = 0;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if(savedInstanceState != null) { 
            score = savedInstanceState.getInt("score", 0)
            score2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("score2", 0)
        }
     }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(bundle: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle)
        bundle.putInt("score", score)
        bundle.putInt("score2", score2)
    }
```